# Unable to send message to groups in SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I'm using SignalR 2.2.1 in my chat application.

I'm adding users to groups and sending messages to the group. While sending a message, I'm fetching the group name from the user object as follows.

I'm unable to send messages to a group whereas sending messages to the caller or all clients works.

Server-side code:

```
public string AddUsersToGroup(string CurrentUserId, string toUserId)
{   
    string strGroupName = GetUniqueGroupName(CurrentUserId, toUserId);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toUserId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUserId))
    {
        string _cnId, _toCnId;
        _cnId = UsersOnline.userObj.Where(item => item.userId == CurrentUserId).Select(item => item.ConnectionIds.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
        _toCnId = UsersOnline.userObj.Where(item => item.userId == toUserId).Select(item => item.ConnectionIds.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
        UsersOnline.userObj.Where(item => item.userId == CurrentUserId).FirstOrDefault().GroupName = strGroupName;
        UsersOnline.userObj.Where(item => item.userId == toUserId).FirstOrDefault().GroupName = strGroupName;

        Groups.Add(_cnId, strGroupName);
        Groups.Add(_toCnId, strGroupName);                               
    }
    return strGroupName;
}

public void Send(string message)
{
    if (Clients != null)
    {
        string _conId = Context.ConnectionId;
        string GroupName = UsersOnline.userObj.Where(item =>   item.ConnectionIds.Contains(_conId)).FirstOrDefault().GroupName;
        Clients.Group(GroupName).broadcastMessage(message); // This doesn't work.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message); // This works.
        Clients.Caller.broadcastmessage(message); // This works.
    }
}

private string GetUniqueGroupName(string CurrentUserId, string toUserId)
{
    return (CurrentUserId.GetHashCode() ^ toUserId.GetHashCode()).ToString();
}
```

Client side code:

```
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {              
    $('#divMessageBoard').append('<span>' + $('<div/>').text(message).html() + '</span><br/>');
    var divMessageBoard = $('#divMessageBoard');
    $("#divMessageBoard").animate({ scrollTop: $("#divMessageBoard")[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);
};
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What is UsersOnline and are you sure you get a correct groupName and the group is not empty?

Comment: @Pawel UsersOnline is a class containing a static List<User> to add and remove users. Yes the group name is correctly assigned to the users but still unable to deliver the message.

Comment: How do you add clients to group? - show the client and the server code.

Comment: @Pawel Please check the updated code above.

Comment: I still don't see the code that calls `AddUsersToGroup` and also the code that sets ConnectionId for the user. Also not sure why you have multiple ConnectionIds for a user - you always use only one/first id.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use gethashcode to generate the name of the group, the results will only match if all the data for the user is identical, and if there is a disconnect, or the connectionid change the group name will no longer be valid for that user. You can use ConnectionId since it is unique for each user. Also Pawel is correct you are creating the groups but you are not adding the user to the group itself.